# memcached result MEMCACHED_NOTFOUND

Tags: php, memcached

i'm trying to use memcached for storing my instagram feed. I'm using zend server and i loaded memcached :

[image]

If i set :

```
$m->set('int', 99);
```

this return bool(false) :

```
var_dump($m->get('int'));
```

this return int(16) : MEMCACHED_NOTFOUND :

```
var_dump($m->getResultCode());
```

so here the full code :

```
$m = new Memcached();
$m->addServer('127.0.0.1', 11211);

$m->set('int', 99);
var_dump($m->get('int'));
```

Comment: Is there a memcached server that listens to `127.0.0.1:11211`?

Comment: well i'm not sure if i missed a step, i thought loading it on zend server would be enough.

should i install it somewhere else?

maybe like it is explained in that post? [link](http://www.glenscott.co.uk/blog/install-memcached-php-extension-on-os-x-snow-leopard/)

Comment: I don't see where they are starting the memcached daemon

Comment: But so should i do something else that loading memcached in zend server (I guess it's the same step in wamp or xampp)

Comment: that's why following tutorials is a terrible practice. Do you understand what is memcached? And what is Zend Server?

Comment: Yea i know zend server good enough i guess, i read on the official php docs what is memcached (it's where i get the code) but it didn't give more information about it so i don't know much about it.

So i'm not sure where to learn more about it and see if i missed a step. If you have any recomendations i'll be glad to have a look.

Comment: well, it's a standalone separated daemon. There is no any "loading memcached in zend server"